# Apply Check on default sort by options

Tags: magento2, toolbar, product-sorting

I just need to apply a check on the default `Sort By` options. Not on all. only one. That when the user is not login, he cannot sort products by price.
Anyone having any idea how to do it.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what Magento version you are using. In future please tag your question accordingly.

The following answer is for M2:

I would write a plugin module that does an 
`afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray()` method to change the output of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()` 
and remove the options depending on user type (eg: if the user is a `Guest user`).

here is the full method to change:

```
    /**
     * Retrieve Attributes Used for Sort by as array
     * key = code, value = name
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['position' => __('Position')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

found in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Config.php`

I hope that helps.